# На сторонним сайте есть элемент, который срабатывает, когда на него наводишь мышь - как выполнять это действие через скрипт?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, консоль

В подробностях:

На сайте ВК, есть необходимость заменять картинку в плохом качестве (`#pv_photo img`) на картинку, адрес которой указывается в "Открыть оригинал" (`pv_more_act_download`), проблема состоит в том, что до тех пор, пока не навести курсор на кнопку "Ещё", на странице не создаётся элемента `pv_more_act_download`. Нужно, чтобы этот элемент создавался без лишних телодвижений.

[image: скриншот]

Цель, как и проблема, довольно глупые, но уже пол дня сижу. Были попытки и найти функцию, которая срабатывает, если навести курсор, были попытки и поискать способы автоматически передвигать курсор к этому элементу. Но знания в этой области у меня ужасные, а руки кривые, поэтому только осталось просить помощи тут.

Comment: @0xdb, зачем? И какой именно текст ты хочешь увидеть? Всё необходимое в вопросе есть.

Comment: @Qwertiy на картинке разве не код? Почему его нельзя добавить как текст?

Comment: @0xdb, нет. Там скриншот того, что до наведения элемента нет в разметке. Отмечена кнопка красным и показано, что элемент то есть, то нет. А всё нужное (`#pv_photo img` и `pv_more_act_download`) указано в тексте вопроса.

Comment: @Qwertiy Понятно, учту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.querySelector(".pv_actions_more").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseenter'))
```

Только учти, что интересующий тебя элемент проявляется асинхронно. Т. е. просто

```
document.getElementById('pv_more_act_download')
```

в следующей строке за событием не сработает.